# One time set up charge ubercart

Tags: ubercart, notifications

I am trying to set up subscription in drupal 7.However i also want to charge the customer with one time set up charge which will not be recurring in nature. 
Ex. If a product cost is $30 per month and set up charge is $15. Then he should only be charged $45 first time. Next month he should be charged only $30 not full $45.
Any ideas about any module or configuration option to achieve this. 
Or will i have to do custom  coding only for this. 
I assume many sites in drupal might already have this functionality achieved.

Regards to all
Smith